# Opposite of Stable Sort in Java (Unstable?)

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, comparator

I need to sort a list of objects in Java by one of their params. This works fine, and when there's a tie, it maintains the previous order.

However, my goal is to port over some ugly code which did its own sort, and I have to preserve the same behavior. In that algorithm, it reverses the previous order in cases of a tie.

For example, if I wanted to sort these objects by the int:

```
{ a, 1}
{ b, 2}
{ c, 1}
```

My code returns: a, c, b

The code I'm porting returns:  c, a, b

My code now is:

```
final Comparator<MyObj> myComparator =
    Comparator.comparingInt(MyObj::getSortWeight)
return myObjList
    .stream()
    .sorted(myComparator)
    .map(//doing some other transformations here)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there a non-hacky way to make it work the same way as the old code did? I don't want to reinvent the wheel on this.

Comment: sounds like you'll have to re-implement `Comparator.comparingInt` and do a swap in case of `==` - shouldn't be too difficult to do!

Comment: @alfasin - That approach won't work.  If the comparator returns anything other than zero for `compare(1, 1)` then you will end up with something that is not a valid ordering ... and the TimSort algorithm will throw an exception (probably).

Comment: @StephenC https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0ff43111ef7fecf8ef6f4261a8cfde58

Comment: I commented on that.

Comment: @StephenC here we go: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/15856a2d25aacc43d0a999157cf2aa96

Comment: You ignored half of my comments :-).  Anyhow, if you really think this will work, post it as an Answer and we can analyse it properly ... and point out the problems.

Comment: @StephenC I'm not sure what else should I comment to ? creating a larger set ? how large do you want it to be ? :)

Comment: Large enough.  You are aware of how TimSort works ... I assume.  And that it behaves differently for small inputs.  Basically, what you have done is working (for you) because you are lucky ... not because it is correct.  The comparator you are supply violates the "contract" that a sort algorithm requires.

Comment: @StephenC So it has to be bigger than 32 items (for the [openJDK](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~martin/webrevs/openjdk7/timsort/raw_files/new/src/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java) implementation), Tim's original implementation used 64 as min for binary sort... ok if I'll have some spare time tonight I might play with it and update this thread.

Comment: Be very careful here. It's quite possible that the old sort doesn't *always* reverse the order of equal items. This is especially true when there are more than two items that have the same value.

Comment: Indeed.  What the behavior is strictly undefined if the comparator violates the contract.  Specifically the contract says `a.compareTo(b) > 0 <=> b.compareTo(a) < 0`

Answer (score 8):

If the goal is to have equal elements in reverse order, you can simply reverse the list before sorting:

```
List<MyObj> copy = new ArrayList<>(myObjList);
Collections.reverse(copy);
return copy.stream()
    .sorted(myComparator)
    .map(//doing some other transformations here)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I was thinking of doing the reversal (of equal elements) at the end, but this is so much simpler.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly the simple solution I was looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure it works if you have, say, 3 items with the same value!

Comment: @alfasin I don't see the problem. Can you be more specific?

Comment: What I'm saying is that the stream may not be *ordered* and in case it doesn't, the function `sorted` will not be stable, so reverting the order of the underlying collection might not help. The reason I'm mentioning it is that the OP described his objects as hashSet which are naturally are unordered.

Comment: @alfasin My solution assumes `myObjList` is a `List<MyObj>`. Where did you see otherwise?

Comment: @shmosel forget the hash/object, focus on the rest of what I wrote: if the stream isn't ordered `sorted` is unstable and this solution won't work. That said, I admit that I don't know how to prove if the stream of `MyObj`  is ordered or not. That's something that I'd love to learn!

Comment: For more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering

Comment: @alfasin `List.stream()` returns an ordered stream, because it derives from the ordered [`List.spliterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#spliterator--).

Comment: I suspect that it's intrinsically ordered (the order of the items in the list) which is not the same as "natural ordering".

Comment: @alfasin See also this quote from your link: *Certain stream sources (such as List or arrays) are intrinsically ordered*

Comment: @alfasin Who's discussing natural ordering? I'm not even sure what you're trying to say anymore. Maybe think it over and try to produce some code demonstrating the problem, assuming there is one.

Comment: And post is in an Answer!!

Comment: @shmosel a stream of integers is naturally ordered but a stream of objects is not necessarily. In the answer that I posted I created a fake `MyInteger` class which has an additional tag and for which the order doesn't exist. Since the OP uses objects, they are not naturally ordered unless his objects implement `Comparable`. As I wrote in my previous comment, my understanding of "intrinsically ordered" is "the same order as they had in the list" - but that doesn't mean that the objects themselves have natural order.